# Adding parameters to Cloud Endpoint causes 404 GoogleJsonResponseException

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I have am having an issue where I completed the sample GCM Messaging (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints)

and everything works fine until I want to add additional parameters to the `registerDevice` method in the the `RegistrationEndpoint` class. I've made sure that I added the `@Named` in before.

Before the change it looks like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "register")
public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId) {
    if (findRecord(regId) != null) {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
        return;
    }
    RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
    record.setRegId(regId);
    //record.setUserName(name);
    //record.setUserProfId(profId);
    ofy().save().entity(record).now();
}
```

And after the change it looks like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "register")
public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId, @Named("name") String name, @Named("profId") String profId) {
    if (findRecord(regId) != null) {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
        return;
    }
    RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
    record.setRegId(regId);
    record.setUserName(name);
    record.setUserProfId(profId);
    ofy().save().entity(record).now();
}
```

Once I added those two parameters, the GCM request fails with the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
```

at this line in my code (in an `AsyncTask`)

```
regService.register(Globals.REG_ID,"Test","Test").execute();
```

But when it the "Test","Test" is removed as in the original tutorial, it works fine!

**In conclusion**, I can't post to the datastore when I added my own parameters with fields I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you introduce new method in Google Cloud Endpoints you have to do:

1. Upload new version to App Engine
2. If you've changed the version name, you have to make it default one in the Developer Console

404 means there's no such method, so I assume you've not done yet one of the steps mentioned above.

If you done above steps just check if the method works using API Explorer

```
https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://appname.appspot.com/_ah/api
```

One more thing. Remember to check the parameters order. From my experience it will rather be `(name, profId, regId)`, but I could be wrong:

```
regService.register("Test", "Test", Globals.REG_ID).execute();
```

Comment: Okay! Should I change the order in my EndPoint method to be alphabetical too? I'll give this a try

Comment: No you don't have to. But the generated methods have their parameters in  alphabetical order, so if you have 3 Strings (or parameters of the same type) you should be aware of this.

Comment: Dumb question, but how do you upload the new version to App Engine? I changed the version to v2 in the API tag header, and I ran the backend locally and it works...and I ran the app code on a mobile device and the error is still occurring. If I check the api-explorer it still says v1 on my appspot site. I feel like there is somewhere in the dev console where you choose v2 but I can't find it!

Comment: Never mind I found it! I forgot you I had to upload it in Android Studio under the Build header. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BrienGerber, remember to **accept** this useful answer!